# setting up cypress in react.js with typescript and jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cypress

I am setting up cypress in my project which is built using react.js, typescript and I am using also jest. but I am getting an error when I am typing this command: `yarn check-type`

here is the error message

```
test/snapshot/VmrFormInternal.test.tsx:278:35 - error TS2339: Property 'toMatchSnapshot' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.

278 expect(EnzymeToJson(subject)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

here are my config files

`tsconfig.spec.json`

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
      "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
  }
```

`cypress.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    // implement node event listeners here
  }
});
```

`tsconfig.lint.json`

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "noEmit": true
    },
    "exclude": []
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
...
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
...
```

i am installing the cypress on my project and this is what i am having as an error message and i am trying to find the answer. if someone come across this please let me know your suggestion to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the jest `toMatchSnapshot` with a Cypress test.

To run a snapshot test in Cypress

- install the package: `npm install --save-dev @cypress/snapshot`
- add to **cypress/support/commands.js** the line: `require('@cypress/snapshot').register()`
- call it with a Cypress command (not Enzyme): `cy.get('body').snapshot()`

Comment: Thank you for your help
sorry i did not mention that i am using yarn for as a package so npm won't work for me. so you mean i should call cy.get('body').snapshot() but .snapshot() doesn't exist as a property or could you clarify just a little bit please ?